# Reducing stretching of a caption gives an error

Tags: errors, captions, margins

I get an error when I add the `stretch=0.80` command to the caption-package as here:

```
\usepackage[font={color=red,footnotesize,%
stretch=0.80},labelsep=quad]{caption}
```

The caption is a simple `\caption{Some text}` in a table environment with no special symbols in the text.

The error message:

```
 Undefined control sequence. \setstretch{Some text}
```

I wish to use the `stretch` parameter to simply change the margin of the caption so it only stretches a smaller width than the text width.

Is it wrong to use the `stretch` parameter here? I don't see the problem as the [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) (top of page 11) doesn't mention any conflicting cases.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You see, without an easy testable case, it can take a week or more till someone finds enough time to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stretch` is connected to package `setspace` and defines how the lines of caption text are stretched. A value less than one means, that everything will look a bit cramped.

To define the margins of the caption, use `margin` ;-)

[image: steeveCaptionStretchMargin]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[font={color=red!50!black,footnotesize,stretch=0.80},labelsep=quad,margin={1cm}]{caption}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}
    \caption{Some text \blindtext}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what strikes me in the visual is that there are big holes after periods, even though the intra-sentence text may look squished.  the holes are much more obvious in the caption than in the regular text.  not nice.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wow, you pay attention :-) Even with `\frenchspacing` it looks quite ugly, `microtype` can do *some* magic.  Should i update the answer with those details?